# Help Understanding Piecewise Defined Laplace Transformations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I understand that I need to convert to Heaviside functions and I think I'm doing that correctly, however my answer is not what it's supposed to be.

Below is one of the problems I am working on, with my workings and interpretation of what the  graph should look like. Could someone please explain how I am meant to get my answer to look like that.

[image: My work]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(t)=g(t)u(t-t_0)$, then the Laplace Transform, $F(s)$, of $f(t)$ is

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty g(t)u(t-t_0)e^{-st}\,dt \\\\
&\int_{t_0}^\infty g(t)e^{-st}\,dt \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, we enforce the substitution $t-t_0=t'$ into $(1)$ to obtain

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty g(t'+t_0)e^{-s(t'+t_0)}\,dt' \tag 2$$

Using $(2)$ with $g(t)=t^2$ and $t_0=5$ yields

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=\int_0^\infty (t+5)^2e^{-s(t+5)}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-5s}\int_0^\infty (t^2+10t+25) e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=e^{-5s}\left(\frac{2}{s^3}+\frac{10}{s^2}+\frac{25}{s}\right)
\end{align}$$

---

Note the in general, if $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t)$, then $e^{-st_0}F(s)$ is the Laplace Transform of $f(t-t_0)$.  For the function $f(t)=t^2$, the Laplace transform is $\frac{2}{s^3}$.

Therefore, the Laplace transform of $(t-5)^2u(t-5)$ is $e^{-5s}\left(\frac{2}{s^3}\right)$.  But then note that $(t-5)^2u(t-5)\ne t^2u(t-5)$.  And this was, I believe, the issue with the OP.

Comment: I did it now using the laplace definition but I don't understand why method didn't work, could you please help me understand.

Comment: Sure.  I've edited and provided a "walk-through."

Comment: I see where I went wrong, thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have learnt yet is $L[f(t-a).u(t-a)]=e^{-as}.L[f(t)]$ which is somewhat tricky to acheive in this problem and what you really need here is just another version of this formula:

$L[f(t).u(t-a)]=e^{-as}.L[f(t+a)]$

Hope it helps!